# Security issues for quantum computers

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Although quantum computers might be highly efficient at hacking conventional computers, might they have an Achilles heel that makes them easily hacked?

Comment: What does it mean to hack a computer? Normally by that you mean hacking the cryptographic security that protects their access

Comment: Off course, such a security system could be circumvented by a direct mechanical or electronic influence introduced remotely since it could operate at the level of the QC hardware and cause the evolving superposition to collapse before being detected by security.

Comment: Perhaps an earth quake (even a mild one) could cause a superposition collapse in all the QC's operating in a geographically significant area.

Comment: The rise of quantum computing initiates a new age in which the accidental collapses of classical physics are augmented by the possibilities envisioned by the rather ambiguous laws of quantum measurement.

Comment: It would seem that in a QC rising technology, that the issue of whether the Copenhagen interp. of QM is complete, becomes an issued of renewed importance. If it misses a few tricks, then the entire QC concept might have to be reconsidered

Answer (score 0):

By continuous time evolution of wave function:

Since QC's require a superposition of memory eigenstates to evolve in real time prior to returning a result by the collapse of the superposition, it seems that if an external agency could, from a remote location, introduce stealth perturbations to the computers internal Hamiltonian, it could be caused to alter the  program in progress to return any desired result.

By discontinuous time evolution of wave function:

Perhaps an acoustic beam directed at the computers hardware would shake things up in such a way that it constitutes a measurement event shutting down the program before it can be officially collapsed.